# Why do I always get to enter a-1 strings in this string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Why do I always get to enter a-1 strings in this string array?

```
public class Source {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Declare the variable
        int a;

        // Read the variable from STDIN
        a = in.nextInt();
        String strs[]=new String[a];
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
        strs[i]=in.nextInt();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why are you reading an int into a String array?

Comment: Do you have an input example? Complete with what you think should be in the array and in a and what the actual result is?

Answer (score 0):

You can change condition in your loop, like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < a - 1; i++) {
    strs[i] = in.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating correctly a number of times equal to `a`. Not `a-1`. So the question appears to be invalid:

```
public class Source {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        // Declare the variable
        int a;
        System.out.print("How many Strings would you like to enter? ");
        // Read the variable from STDIN
        a = in.nextInt();
        String[] strs = new String[a]; // this will fail for certain values of `a`
        for(int i=0; i<a; i++) {
            System.out.format("Enter String number %d: ", i+1);
            strs[i]= in.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Result: " + Arrays.toString(strs));
    }
} 
}
```

run:

> How many Strings would you like to enter? 2
>
> Enter String number 1: Apple
>
> Enter String number 2: Pen
>
> Result: [Apple, Pen]